# Unresolved package/class Error in Android studio in AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

A friend of mine sent me some code I'm supposed to work on and I am running into errors.
He told me that it has been working on his computer but I get errors in the Manifest.xml file.

The first error ist the unresolved package/class Error. I tried to fix this by checking the correct directory multiple times, everything seems fine but I still get the error. What I'm finding odd is, that there is only one `build.gradle` file. I tried rebuilding, but nothing happens. I hope that you can help me.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file is in the following directory:

```
> C:\Android Stuff\MimikApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="psychosomatik.mimikapp">

    <application
        android:name="psychosomatik.mimikapp.LoginController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ScoreboardActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScoreboardActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity…………
```

[image]

The error is shown in the following line:

```
> android:name="psychosomatik.mimikapp.LoginController"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a redundancy here :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="psychosomatik.mimikapp">

    <application
        android:name="psychosomatik.mimikapp.LoginController"
```

If you specify the package name in the manifest tag, you don't have to use "absolute reference" in the application or activity tags.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="psychosomatik.mimikapp">

    <application
        android:name="LoginController"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to sign you Application name cuz it related to application tag.

```
android:name="psychosomatik.mimikapp.YourApplicatyionName"
```

It have to me something like as I see.

```
android:name="psychosomatik.mimikapp.MimikApp"
```